# Issues using 'info.hoang8f.widget.FButton'

Tags: android, android-layout

I am unable to see any color change for the button below

[image]

Its color as been assigned and all that.The UI view is as in the image

[image]

```
      <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp" />

    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignActive"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `android:backgroundTint` to modify the actual tint of your background, or use `android:background` to change the whole background